# How to know and instantiate only one class implemented in a Python module dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-importlib

Suppose in "./data_writers/excel_data_writer.py", I have:

```
from generic_data_writer import GenericDataWriter

class ExcelDataWriter(GenericDataWriter):
   def __init__(self, config):
       super().__init__(config)
       self.sheet_name = config.get('sheetname')

   def write_data(self, pandas_dataframe):
       pandas_dataframe.to_excel(
           self.get_output_file_path_and_name(), # implemented in GenericDataWriter
           sheet_name=self.sheet_name,
           index=self.index)
```

In "./data_writers/csv_data_writer.py", I have:

```
from generic_data_writer import GenericDataWriter

class CSVDataWriter(GenericDataWriter):
   def __init__(self, config):
       super().__init__(config)
       self.delimiter = config.get('delimiter')
       self.encoding = config.get('encoding')

   def write_data(self, pandas_dataframe):
       pandas_dataframe.to_csv(
           self.get_output_file_path_and_name(), # implemented in GenericDataWriter
           sep=self.delimiter,
           encoding=self.encoding,
           index=self.index)
```

In "./datawriters/generic_data_writer.py", I have:

```
import os

class GenericDataWriter:
   def __init__(self, config):
       self.output_folder = config.get('output_folder')
       self.output_file_name = config.get('output_file')
       self.output_file_path_and_name = os.path.join(self.output_folder, self.output_file_name)
       self.index = config.get('include_index') # whether to include index column from Pandas' dataframe in the output file
```

Suppose I have a JSON config file that has a key-value pair like this:

```
{
"__comment__": "Here, user can provide the path and python file name of the custom data writer module she wants to use."
"custom_data_writer_module": "./data_writers/excel_data_writer.py"

"there_are_more_key_value_pairs_in_this_JSON_config_file": "for other input parameters"
}
```

In "main.py", I want to import the data writer module based on the `custom_data_writer_module` provided in the JSON config file above. So I wrote this:

```
import os
import importlib

def main():
    # Do other things to read and process data

    data_writer_class_file = config.get('custom_data_writer_module')
    data_writer_module = importlib.import_module\
            (os.path.splitext(os.path.split(data_writer_class_file)[1])[0])

    dw = data_writer_module.what_should_this_be?   # <=== Here, what should I do to instantiate the right specific data writer (Excel or CSV) class instance?
    for df in dataframes_to_write_to_output_file:
        dw.write_data(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As I asked in the code above, I want to know if there's a way to retrieve and instantiate the class defined in a Python module assuming that there is ONLY ONE class defined in the module. Or if there is a better way to refactor my code (using some sort of pattern) without changing the structure of JSON config file described above, I'd like to learn from Python experts on StackOverflow. Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: In my opinion - the simplest and most readable solution would be going the explicit route. I.e., import all the relevant sub-classes in your main module, and use an `if/else` statement to resolve and instantiate a specific `DataWriter`.

Comment: @misha, Thanks for the suggestion. I actually don't know what other custom data writer modules will be implemented and used in this generic data processing module, so adding `if-else` is not quite what I'm hoping to go. But your suggestion definitely noted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with `vars`:

```
cls1,=[v for k,v in vars(data_writer_module).items()
       if isinstance(v,type)]
dw=cls1(config)
```

The comma enforces that exactly one class is found.  If the module is allowed to do anything like `from collections import deque` (or even `foo=str`), you might need to filter based on `v.__module__`.

Comment: OP could also check if `__all__` is defined and use that to avoid catching import classes if `__all__` is used in the module(s).

Comment: @modesitt: Certainly, although that level of assistance from the module might as well be expressed as `use_this_class=Foo`.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thank you for suggesting a solution (really like the suggestion of using `,` to prevent selecting more than one class). I will try it and once it works, I will accept the solution. I'm wondering if you could elaborate a bit on what you mean by the last line of your answer. I interpret that as if I can import `deque`, I can filter using something like `[v.__module__ for k,v in ...`? Thanks in advance for your follow-up explanation!

Comment: @modesitt Thank you for suggesting an alternative to the answer above. How do I check if `__all__` is defined? Is it just reading through the code and see if `__all__` variable is declared? Say, if I see `__all__` is defined, how could I use that? If you could elaborate a bit on what you mean by "use that (`__all__`) to avoid catching import classes, I'd like to learn one more approach (to expand my Python knowledge). Thank you!

Comment: `hasattr(data_writer_module, "__all__")`. @DavisHerring is right though. If you are doing that - `exported_clas = ...` is more explicit  - I just suggested it in case this is, for some reason, code you do not control.

Comment: @user1330974: You would just add something like `and getattr(v,"__module__",None)==data_writer_module.__name__` to the list comprehension condition.